# how imitate big screen size(5600 * 1050) in my local laptop(1280 * 1024) and use media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to imitate big screen size(5600 * 1050) in my local laptop(1280 * 1024), and  use media query.

**I had try set meta viewport width=5600, but it seems not work.** I hope the wrapper div should be blue color because the viewport width is bigger than 5600px already.

my test code:

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      .wrapper {
        width: 100px;
        /* float: left; */
      }

      @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 5600px) {
        .wrapper {
          background-color: red;
        }
      }

      @media (min-width: 5600px) {
        .wrapper {
          background-color: blue;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=5600, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">aaa</div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px;">ddd</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

added picture
[image]
[image]

Comment: [You can simulate Mobile Devices with Device Mode in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/). You can define the resoultion and zoom levels.

Comment: but it still some problem, as the picture additional added show, there is a div where position in right side, but I can not see it, is any way to show the scroll bar so that I can see all screen in 100% zoom

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google Chrome, you can use the dev tools to do this.

Step 1. Hit F12 on your keyboard
Step 2. Click the little mobile device icon on the top left of the dev tools window.
Step 3. Select "Responsive" on the device selection dropdown at the top of your browser window.
Step 4. Set zoom to around 50% or lower, so the new resolution fits on your screen
Step 5. Click and drag the edges of the responsive window until you reach desired resolution, or just enter the resolution in the input boxes at the top of the window.
https://i.snag.gy/DeJv5j.jpg

See this link for more information: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Comment: Also I would add that you can set the zoom to 50% or manually set the desired resolution

Comment: @ksav Thank you, almost forgot that part. Added it to my answer :)

Comment: thanks, but it still some problem, as the picture additional added show, there is a div where position in right side, but I can not see it, is any way to show the scroll bar so that I can see all screen in 100% zoom.

Comment: @josh_wbs, and i found a website that is what i want imitate in chrome develop tool:http://quirktools.com/screenfly/.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it, easily with develop tools:

[image]
Work for you?

Comment: thanks, but it still some problem, as the picture additional added show, there is a div where position in right side, but I can not see it, is any way to show the scroll bar so that I can see all screen in 100% zoom

Comment: I got it. Update your code to me see, its possible?

Comment: of course, I have update code below. and i found a website that is what i want imitate in chrome develop tool:quirktools.com/screenfly. thanks very much! I spent two days on that, but failed...

Comment: this is code in gist https://gist.github.com/dyh333/c205e25fbbc7672a093ddbaa505ed08e

Comment: Dude your problem is with `initial-scale=100` try change to 1